# Is it possible to write C++ function that swaps the input without using any conditional statement?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to write a C++ function like if we enter 9 then the program return 6 and if we input 6 the program return us 9 as output? Without using any conditional statement?

Comment: `15 - x`?  `54 / x`?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can use a bidirectional mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for functions that satisfy:

```
f(x) = y
f(y) = x
```

for some fixed `x` and `y`.

You can look for involutions, which are functions that satisfy:

```
f(f(x)) = x
```

Search for those that you can implement without conditionals, which *usually* means using only integers and the built-in arithmetic operators.

For instance, XOR:

```
f(x) = x ^ N
```

for some fixed `N` that you adjust using the given `x`/`y`.

Comment: I mean that we only allow to enter one input 9 or 6 and then given tha output either 9,6? So can we check is it 6 or 9 enter as a input?